# Saving as PDF in word using VBA causes changes to the document

Tags: vba, pdf, ms-word

I use the following code to quickly convert an active word document to PDF and save to desktop. It works very well but when I go to exit the document immediately afterwards it always asks if I want to make changes, when none should have been made.

Is there a way I can prevent it making these invisible changes to the document so that it will just immediately quit (if it was saved just before the export, for example).

```
Sub PdfToDesktop()
'
'
Dim DeskTop As String
DeskTop = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders("Desktop")

Dim fileNameOnly As String
Dim fileNameDot As Integer
fileNameDot = InStr(1, ActiveDocument.Name, ".")

fileNameOnly = Left(ActiveDocument.Name, fileNameDot - 1)

    ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:= _
        DeskTop & "\" & fileNameOnly & ".pdf", ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF, _
        OpenAfterExport:=True, OptimizeFor:=wdExportOptimizeForPrint, Range:= _
        wdExportAllDocument, From:=1, To:=1, Item:=wdExportDocumentContent, _
        IncludeDocProps:=True, KeepIRM:=True, CreateBookmarks:= _
        wdExportCreateNoBookmarks, DocStructureTags:=True, BitmapMissingFonts:= _
        True, UseISO19005_1:=False
    ChangeFileOpenDirectory DeskTop
End Sub
```

Comment: If you add `ActiveDocument.Saved = True` then you won't be prompted to save changes (but note if you had made other changes prior to running the export macro then those also might be lost if you do not save on close...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't want to save the document or close it as a part of the PDF generation so I used this line at the beginning of the code `If ActiveDocument.Saved = True Then fileSaved = True` to store the save status and then this line at the end to restore that `If fileSaved = True Then ActiveDocument.Saved = True`

Answer (score 2):

Either have the code close the document with:

```
ActiveDocument.Close SaveChanges:= False
End Sub
```

Or save the document again at the end of the code:

```
ActiveDocument.Save
End Sub
```

Put either of these right at the end.

This doesn't entirely answer your question, but will prevent the pop-up window from appearing when you close the document (either through code in the first method or manually later in the second).